# How build xlsx file with many rows it corectly?

Tags: java, oracle, apache-poi, xlsx

I tried to build a report from Oracle to xlsx, but my server freezes. I do it:

```
int i = 0;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    //Create a new row in current sheet
    Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
    //Create a new cell in current row
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(resultSet.getInt(1));
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(2));
    row.createCell(2).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(3));
    row.createCell(3).setCellValue(resultSet.getLong(4));
    row.createCell(4).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(5));
    row.createCell(5).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(6));
    row.createCell(6).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(7));
    row.createCell(7).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(8));
    row.createCell(8).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(9));
    row.createCell(9).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(10));
    row.createCell(10).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(11));
    row.createCell(11).setCellValue(resultSet.getLong(12));
    i++;
 }
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\new.xls"));
 wb.write(out);
 out.close();
 resultSet.close();
 sqlStatment.close();
 sqlConnection.close();
```

My `resultSet` has ~ 500 000 rows. I not got error. How to build xlsx file with many rows correctly?

Comment: Do you really need xlsx file: is for you possible alternative to generate CSV file and then import it into xlsx using Excel function import data from file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that Apache-POI (like most of APIs) try to build the xls file in memory. To solve this you have two options:

- [SXSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf). This is a streaming solution built with the Apache POI library. It works similarly to what you already have, but flushes extra content to disk and should allow you to handle big files easily.
- Alternatively you can just write CSV files. This way you can ditch the whole POI library and write plain CSV files. Those can be written line-by-line using standard Java codes (or a CSS library if you feel it is needed), then converted into XLSX if needed by the user of that report. Excel opens CSV files without too much hustle nowadays.

Comment: CSS files == CSV files ?

Comment: 200 000 rows export cool! Now I start 3 000 000 rows and wait)))))

Comment: CSS vs CSV: I have been doing frontend the whole week... Sorry.

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (1048576) outside allowable range (0..1048575) - how can this be solved?

Comment: That value is 2^20-1. That is the Microsoft Excel's limit unfortunately. Your question was about exporting 500k rows. Even 1m would work. But not more than that.Above this limit even CSV import would fail, so you need start splitting your data into chunks of 1m rows.

Comment: Yes, I understand what I was asking about 500,000. I noted your answer as correct. and it is simply gorgeous! but this is my greed))) can prompt as to divide the pages of the file?

Comment: Could you please rephrase this question? I don't get it.